# i have a form i want to submitted form with post method with out refresh page but here post is not working

Tags: php, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#form1').bind('click', function (event) {

event.preventDefault();// using this page stop being refreshing 

          $.ajax({ type: 'POST',
            url: 'car1.php',
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
            success: function () {
             // alert('form was submitted');    
             $("#allyears").hide();    
             $("#clickresult").show(); } }); });});
    </script>
//year show
while($row_year1=mysql_fetch_array($result_year1))
            { ?> 
<a href="#"><input type="submit" class="submitbutton1" tabindex="-1" name="submitbutton" value="<?php echo $row_year1['years']; ?>" id="show<?php echo $row_year1['years']; ?>"  /></a>
<?php } ?>
//result
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitbutton']))

{

$submitbutton=$_POST['submitbutton'];    

echo $submitbutton;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why people are downvoting this question, but your problem is your event listener. You are checking if the form has been clicked other than if the form has been submitted. If you want to use the `click` event listener, you would bind it to the submit button instead. But this isn't suggested since sometimes the submit button isn't clicked and the user presses enter instead to trigger the form to submit. So stick with the `submit` event listener on the form.

http://jsfiddle.net/gaQK3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form1').bind('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'car1.php',
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
            success: function () {
               alert('form was submitted');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Also just a few notes about your other code.

1) Stop using the `mysql_` functions. They are now deprecated. You should use PDO or MySQLi. I prefer PDO and believe it will have better future support.

2) Make your nested code even. In your Javascript you close all of the tags on the very last line all together. This is very hard to follow. In my code example you can see exactly what happens.

3) Separate your Javascript and PHP. I don't know if you combined them for the question's purpose, but don't have them in the same file.

4) Add error handling for the Ajax request along with the `success` handling. At one point or another the request is going to fail and you will want to alert the user to try again.